# Application package 'androidmanifest.xml' must have a minimum of two segments

Tags: android

I am attempting to upload an already existing app to the Samsung store via the [100% Indie](http://www.100percentindie.com/) website. But the automated submission process **demands** that the apk file is simply nameofapp.apk with no "." characters allowed before the ".apk". So I changed the package name in my manifest like so:

WAS: package="com.mycompany.mygame"

NOW: package="mygame"

But then I got the error - Application package 'androidmanifest.xml' must have a minimum of two segments. And there appears to be no way round this. I could just create my multi-segment signed apk and then manually rename it... but I'm nervous as to whether this is kosher. Do I have any other options?

Comment: @Prakhar is right, you need to change your package name back to what it was.  Your package name has no influence on your APK file name.

Comment: Prakhar may be correct - but he's not answering my question.

Comment: What do you mean 'other options'?  You have a very simple option - change your package name back.  When you export your APK from Eclipse it lets you choose the file name anyways

Comment: "lets you choose the file name anyways" - yes that's the answer... I hadn't noticed that (till just now) because my destination path was so long it didn't fit in the box and I didn't see that I could edit the file name on the end of it. I had assumed it was just showing me a directory name.

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer below

Comment: @Mick, nameofapp.apk is not the same com.packagename.nameofapp in manifest. They probably asks just correct filename in filesystem from which you upload it ? By which name you saved your release apk file ? if com.mycompany.mygame.apk and upload fails, just rename file itself, to let's say mygame.apk; there is no relation with apk filename and manifest's package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your package names like it was:

```
com.mycompany.mygame
```

The package name doesn't affect the name of the APK.  In fact, Eclipse lets you choose a file name when you export the application.  So renaming the package won't change the file name.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Keep guts to say the reason if you downvoted the answer... Happy to see that you removed your downvote.

Comment: Looks like your answer has no downvotes/upvotes?  Don't throw out such hasty accusations

Comment: Or someone downvoted and then someone else upvoted?  Or one of a million other explanations.  I don't come to SO to get patronized.

Answer (score 0):

this means that it is saying that the package must contain to segment do remove this line and type that one.

```
package="mygame"
```

**TO**

```
package="com.mygame"
```

enjoy...

Comment: That doesn't really solve my problem. I have edited the question to make the problem slightly clearer.

Comment: please explain your problem so that i can help you